Why can we use Bose-Einstein statistics in this expression for number density
In a system with $N$ particles in some volume $V$ in contact with a reservoir of temperature $T$, we find that
$$\bar{n_i}=\frac{g_i}{e^{\frac{{\epsilon}_i -\mu}{kT}} \pm 1}$$
depending on whether the particles are fermions or bosons. In the case of low $T$, we get $\bar{n_i} \approx g_{i} e^{\frac{\mu -{\epsilon}_{i}}{kT}}$ .
In some cosmology textbooks I've looked at, they state a formula for the number density of some species as $d_i=g_i e^{\frac{\mu}{kT}}\int{e^{\frac{{-\epsilon _i}}{kT}}d^3 p}$, which is essentially integrating over the approximation above. If I am not mistaken, this refers to the number of particles of species i (not energy level) per unit volume. There's two things I am confused about: where is any reference to volume made in the equation? The BE/FD distributions should give the total number of particles in a certain energy state over the total volume, correct?
The second thing im confused about: we have $\sum \bar{n_i}=N$ where we sum over all distinct energy states. If we assumed the energy spectrum was approximately continuous, shouldn't we have something like $N=\int{\bar{n_i} dE}$, not $N=\int{\bar{n_i} d^3 p}$? I dont get why the equation integrates over momentum instead of energy--its not like $\bar{n_i}$ is the average number of particles in some region of phase space, so why integrate over momentum?
Overall it seems like the equation for $d_i$ is treating the BE/FD distributions  as the number density over phase space (i.e. the expected number of particles to be in a certain volume of phase space), while the equations dont seem to describe this. Am I wrong?

The units aren't making much sense to me. $d_i$ has units of momentum$^3$, and you're proposed $\int\bar n_i\ \text dE$ has units of energy (or number$\cdot$energy)

@BioPhysicist I know that expression wouldn't be correct and there would have to be some other term to correct the units. I was just trying to say I was confused where momentum came into play--integrating over momentum might give us the correct units, but why does it give us the number density?

This is usually discussed toward the beginning of any solid state textbook.  The authors of those cosmology books probably assume that you have a comprehensive education in physics up to that point...
First of all, I see $\mu$ in the formulas, and I assume that we are using the grand canonical ensemble.  Your system is in contact with a heat bath and a particle reservoir; it cannot have a fixed N.  Instead, $\mu$ controls the equilibrium number of particles in your system.
Let's start with a very simple toy system, where a boson can only ever have energy $\epsilon$.  We agree that the equilibrium number of boson is
$$
\bar{N}(\epsilon) = \frac{1}{\exp\left[(\epsilon-\mu)/kT\right]-1}.
$$
What if we have a bunch of energy levels $\lbrace \epsilon_{i}\rbrace$?  Easy.  The total number of particles is just $\sum_{i} \bar{N}(\epsilon_{i})$.
But here's the first caveat.  If there is degeneracy, for example if $\epsilon_{1} = \epsilon_{2} = \dots = \epsilon_{k}$, you count the same energy k times in the sum.  Now you see why the sum/integral is over momentum, not energy.  For particles in a box, the energy levels are given by $\epsilon(\vec{p}) = p^2/2m$, and each different $\vec{p}$ counts as a distinct level.
And finally let's see how a number becomes a density.  Consider a cubic box of side $L$.  The quantized momentum will be of the form
$$
\vec{p} = \frac{2\pi}{L} (k_x, k_y, k_z)
$$
where the $k_{i}$'s are integers.  You sum over all allowed $\vec{p}$ for the total number inside the box.  But summation is difficult, if only we can do an integral instead...
Notice that, in each direction, the allowed momentum changes by increments of $\Delta p_i = 2\pi/L$.  Assuming $L$ is large, we do the approximation
$$
\sum_{\vec{p}}
= \left(\frac{L}{2\pi}\right)^3 \sum_{\vec{p}} \Delta p_x \Delta p_y \Delta p_z
\approx V \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}
$$
And that is where you get the volume of space out of seemingly nowhere.

Thank you very much for your response. If I am understanding correctly, taking the integral over momentum essentially allows us to account for the $g_i$'s (since those were supposed to account for degeneracy). If I did the math right, this means $\int{d^3p}=4\pi \int{dE \ m\sqrt{2mE}}$ (assuming spherical symmetry). It seems almost too nice for it to work out like this in general...
If you have a reference I can consult for further clarification that would be extremely helpful... as a student self learning its been quite difficult to clarify these seemingly minor inconsistencies

I went through the calculations and ended up at your answer. To clarify, this only works in the case of 0 interactions between particles in a box with the reservoir having "infinite"/very large energy?

The point is, if you have a box of finite volume, strictly speaking you get a sum and not an integral.  And you always get the extra V when you approximate the sum as an integral.  I think your $g_i$ only accounts for stuff like spin degeneracy, but not the $\sqrt{E}$ density of state you write down here.  As for reference, any solid state book will talk about this in chapter 2 (chapter 1 is always general handwaving, you know.)  Piers Coleman's "Intro to many-body physics" is quite accessible.  Or try Ashcroft & Mermin if you prefer old classics.

I was getting the wrong answer because I didn't know how to account for the density of states--looks like this can be evaluated directly via integrating energy, same as your method but interesting to see that this works: if $\Gamma(E)=\sum_{e_i <E} \sim L_x L_y L_z \frac{4\pi}{3}\frac{2mE}{(\bar{h} \pi)^2}^{3/2}*2^{-3}$ (1/8 since x,y,z>0), $\sum_{e_i} f(e_i)=\int{f(e_i)d\Gamma}=\int{f(e_i)\frac{d\Gamma}{dE}dE}$. changing variables gives $\int{f(e(\vec{p}))\frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi \bar{h})^3}}$. cool to see it work using this method as well (even though its essentially the same as yours)

sorry for the messy latex--ran out of space. but thanks a lot for clarifying. makes much more sense now. I assumed this was a result of some much more complicated logic but failed to see there were (very) simplifying assumptions put In place. this kind of upsets me since when I began learning stat mech one of the first things I did was derive that $\Gamma$... would've saved me a massive headache if I tried to use it earlier

Glad to help.  Usually this language of density of state is more useful if you restrict yourself near a Fermi surface, where it stays approximately a constant.  Otherwise I, for one, wouldn't even want to touch it.
